# How can I pass the return value from this method to another class using Java?

Tags: java

I created a method that returns a row of arrays via user input. I managed to display the set of inputted number on the same class using `System.out.println` by assigning each value in userDigits.
My question is, how can I pass the same value in another class?

```
public class LottoTicket extends Ticket {

public int NUM_DIGITS = 5;
public int[] userDigits = new int[NUM_DIGITS];

@Override
public void buyTicket() {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int number = 0;
    double amount = 0;
    System.out.println("-------=======LOTTO TICKET SCREEN=======--------");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("There are three Types (Prima, Ambo and Terro)");
    System.out.print("Please select one (P, A, T): ");
    String lotteryOption = input.next();

    switch (lotteryOption) {
        case "P": {
            break;
        }
        case "A": {
            break;
        }
        case "T": {

           amount = getAmount(amount);
           getUserData(userDigits);
           int ticketSold;
            ticketSold = +1;
            int tik = ticketSold +1;
            System.out.println(amount);

            System.out.println("Your numbers are:  " + userDigits[0] + " "
                    + userDigits[1] + " " + userDigits[2] + " " + userDigits[3]
                    + " " + userDigits[4] + " ");
            System.out.println("Ticket/s Sold: " + tik);
            System.out.println("Thank you for playing");
            Ticket.pressAnyKeyToContinue();
            LotteryApplication.loginScreen();
            break;
        }
        default: {
            System.out.println("Invalid Input. Please try again.");
            System.out.println("");
            buyTicket();
            break;
        }
    }
}


@Override
public double getAmount(double amount) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please enter amount of money: ");
    amount = input.nextDouble();
    //input.close();
    return amount;
}

@Override
public int getUserData(int[] userInput) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Choose a number from 1 to 90: ");
    userDigits[0] = input.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Choose a number from 1 to 90: ");
    userDigits[1] = input.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Choose a number from 1 to 90: ");
    userDigits[2] = input.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Choose a number from 1 to 90: ");
    userDigits[3] = input.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Choose a number from 1 to 90: ");
    userDigits[4] = input.nextInt();

    //key.close();
    //Returns last value of array
    return userDigits[4];
}
//public int userDigits[];
public static void printTicket(){

   // System.out.println(getUserData.userDigits[4]);
   // for (int i = 0; i < array.length)
}

}
```

Comment: could you post a more workable code?

Comment: Also where do you have this array and where do you want to pass it?

Comment: This is very repetitive code; you should be using loops. I mean really, writing the same code 5 times instead of a `for (int i = 0; i < userDigits.length; i++) {...}`? Also, where do you even use `userInput` and `input`? They are useless.

Comment: When you call `getUserData` you are passing a value to an instance of a class.  I suggest you fllow the example you have in your code already.

Comment: Here is all the code I have in this class, so basically what it does, the app (Lottery) asks the user to input 5 number by calling the getUserData method which does the whole process. The data is then displayed after the method is called. My main concern is how I'm going to pass that same value into another class so I could compare it with the random generated lottery numbers

Comment: @N.Cre One of the principles for questions on Stack Overflow is *Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable*. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. In this case, please make the code more minimal to *just* showcase your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in this case, since you defined `userDigits` as `public`, you can do it easily - it is accessible to any class that has a visibility to your instance of `LottoTicket`. With the current setup you could do something like this:

```
// you need to instantiate LottoTicket somewhere in your app
LottoTicket ticket = new LottoTicket();

// get the input from user
ticket.buyTicket();

// at this point you can access the numbers and pass them to some other method like this
checkNumbers(ticket.userDigits);
```

The example posted above needs you to provide a method `checkNumbers` that has, for example, the following signature:

```
public void checkNumbers(int[] numbers) {
// the comparison code goes here...
```

Also, this is somewhat unrelated to your question, but I'd like to point out two issues with your current code:

1. defining class fields as `public` is done rather rarely, more common approach is to define these as `private` and provide methods for getting/setting the field values; this restricts the operation on these fields to only those you allow - having `public` field allows anyone who has a visibility to that field to perform basically any operations, which is usually not what you want
2. you call `buyTicket()` from `default` in case user didn't select valid lottery type; in extreme cases this could lead to `StackOverflowError` - better approach would be to use a loop that keeps asking user for input until a valid one is provided

Hope this helps at least a bit.

Answer (score -3):

```
        You can easily pass input array to method of another class arguments.

    class PassValue{
     public static void display(int[] elements){
      Anotherclass obj= new Anotherclass();
      obj.display2(elements);
    }
    }
   class Anotherclass{

     public void display2(int[] values){

       do whatever you want
    }
   }
```

Comment: Formatting fixed. Gaurav: in the future, please try to fix the formatting of your posted code; else you're making it hard for others to read, which I'm sure is not your goal.

Comment: OK, now you just made the formatting worse. Why do I bother?

Comment: @Gaurav Srivastav can you please format it according to my solution? Thanks